# Error message: The system cannot find the file specified

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013

Considering only this code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    int x=0, y=0;
    printf("PROGRAM:\nPlease type x ");     
    scanf("%i", x);                         
    printf("\nPlease type y");          
    scanf("%i", y);

    printf("\nx * y = %i", x*y);                 
    printf("\nx / y = %i", x/y);                
    printf("\nx % y = %i", x%y);                 

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

**Hint 1:** *This issue is not about the code itself.... I think any code would show the same error message!!*

After executing the code there is always an error message popping up with the contents

```
Unable to start program 'D:\Path of My Programm\MyProgram.exe'.
The system cannot find the file specified.
```

Then this error message appears always after I clicked ok in the error message pop up window:

The output is:

```
1> Build started: Project: 2, Configuration: Debug Win32
1>cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdC4996'
Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped
```

and there is an error shown:

```
Error 1 error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdC4996'
C:\Users\Nobody\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects\2\2\cl 2
```

**Hint 2:** *Under project >> properties >> advanced >> Disable specific warnings
        I put already the following: C4996;%(DisableSpecificWarnings)*

Any idea how to solve the error mentioned above??

I tried the following things to get rid of the issue without success:

1. Put a shorter file name and project name!
2. Create a new project with the same code contents but save the project under the default path: `C:\Users\Nobody\Documents\Visual Studio 2013\Projects`

Comment: This is no file-name or project-name issue. **You get errors during build**. The compiler generates no output since you're passing invalid parameters to it (cl : Command line error D8021: invalid numeric argument '/wdC4996' Build: 0 succeeded, **1 failed**, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped). Fix the errors and the compiler/linker will create your executable. Remove the switch `/wdC4996` from the compiler options.

Comment: you will get trouble as well with the % sign in your printf. change to: printf("\nx %% y = %i", x%y);

Comment: Hello Bluepixy, I´m not sure if I removed the switch /wdC4996 from the compiler options correct. 

I removed now the xxx under Project >> Properties >> C/C++ >> All -options >> Disable Specific 

Warnings. Or is that wrong, where are then the compiler options exactly?

Comment: 2. when I execute again it pops up the same error message ->  and shows:

Error 1 error C1083: Cannot open source file: 'stdafx.cpp': No such file or directory 

D:\Chris Zeug 106 GB\VS_Programme\GB_3.1 Rechenprogramm\GB_3.1 Rechenprogramm\c1 GB_3.1 

Rechenprogramm

Error 2 error C4996: 'scanf': This function or variable may be unsafe. Consider using 

scanf_s instead. To disable deprecation, use _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS. See online help for 

details. d:\chris zeug 106 gb\vs_programme\gb_3.1 rechenprogramm\gb_3.1 rechenprogramm

\gb_3.1 rechenprogramm.cpp 12 1   GB_3.1 Rechenprogramm

Comment: try `scanf("%i", x);` --> `scanf_s("%i", &x);` , `scanf("%i", y);` --> `scanf_s("%i", &y);`